# display all object privileges granted EXCEPT SYS

Tags: sql, oracle

As SYS to display all object privileges granted to all users but only not for sys.

What the command would be?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you are asking, you'd run something like this:

```
select * 
from dba_tab_privs 
where grantor not in ('SYS', 'SYSTEM', 'CTXSYS', 'XDB', 'MDSYS');
```

---

FYI, try to remember that `dictionary` exists. It reveals a lot of useful information, so - feel free to search it and learn what each of tables (views, actually) contains. For example:

```
SQL> select * from dictionary
  2  where lower(comments) like '%priv%'
  3     or lower(table_name) like '%priv%';

TABLE_NAME                     COMMENTS
------------------------------ --------------------------------------------------
USER_COL_PRIVS                 Grants on columns for which the user is the owner,
                                grantor or grantee

ALL_COL_PRIVS                  Grants on columns for which the user is the granto
                               r, grantee, owner,
                                or an enabled role or PUBLIC is the grantee

DBA_COL_PRIVS                  All grants on columns in the database
<snip>
```